# asp.net mvc and unicode routes and links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unicode, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm developing a unicode web application (in hebrew).
and my route looks like:
"SomeUnicodeHebrewWord/{CategoryId}/{CategoryName}/{Page}

When i use the actionlink the SomeUnicodeHebrewWord and CategoryName (also in hebrew) are getting html encoded. how can i avoid that?
can't i have the links created with th hebrew characters? it is important for SEO reasons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding HTMLEncoding and URIEncoding is not important for SEO reasons. Maybe there are search engines out there that doesn't understand those encodings, but such half-assed search engines aren't going to impact on your market success. Just worry about professional search engines; all professional search engines (and I'm not just talking about the big ones, **all** of them) understand how web pages work.

Beyond that, I'd make sure that every object the string is met by understands appropriate encodings (UTF-16 in terms of the first level of .NET processing, UTF-8 in terms of input and output to and from the web). However, it may be a good idea to have links based on the string output URI encoded (the %xx type of encoding, not the &#xXXX; encoding) as some user-agents out there have less issues with such URIs than with IURIs (they're both understood perfectly, and as equivalent by modern search engines) while more modern user-agents will hide the encoding from users, so you get backwards-compatibility without hurting users of modern browsers, or search engines.

Comment: Hi,

Maybe its not important but it looks better as a URL.
The thing is that problem is a hebrew word in the route not in a query string parameter, it seems like the engine is doing html encode on anything rendered

Comment: What exactly are you seeing. HTML-encoding doesn't change Hebrew (put <%=Server.HtmlEncode("שָׁלוֹם")%> into a page and you get שָׁלוֹם output into the source) unless necessary because you are using a character encoding in which Hebrew letters are impossible (which is a bad idea). Meanwhile however, Hebrew letters are not allowed in URIs only in IURIs (internationalised URIs). There are still some browsers that can't go IURI -> URI, so putting a URI in the source and letting the browser go -> IURI if sophisticated enough isn't a bad idea.